# I'm trying to pass in my lat and lng as an array into the center property of google map api

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

```
import { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import Search from "../Utils/Search";
import SimpleMap from "./SimpleMap";

/**
 * A React component to render the map page
 * @date 3/13/2023 - 2:04:02 PM
 *
 * @export
 * @class MapPage
 * @typedef {MapPage}
 * @extends {Component}
 */

export default class MapPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            lat: 1.3402,
            lng: 103.6755
        };
        this.handleCoordinatesChange = this.handleCoordinatesChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleCoordinatesChange(lat, lng) {
        this.setState({
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <div className="main-content-container">
                    <Search onCoordinatesChange={this.handleCoordinatesChange} />
                    {console.log("Passed in lat and lng" + this.state.lat)}
                    <SimpleMap center={[this.state.lat, this.state.lng]} />
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Above is my Mappage component

```
import React from "react";
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{text}</div>;

export default function SimpleMap({ center }) {
  /*const defaultProps = {
    zoom: 15
  };*/

  return (
    // Important! Always set the container height explicitly
    <div style={{ height: '100%', width: '80%' }}>
      <GoogleMapReact
        bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "x" }}
        center={center}
        defaultZoom={15}
      >
        {console.log("The centre is" + center)}
        <AnyReactComponent
          lat={1.3402}
          lng={103.6755}
          text="My Marker"
        />
      </GoogleMapReact>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The above is my simple map api

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Search(props) {
    const [searchVal, setSearchVal] = useState('');
    const [addresses, setAddresses] = useState([]);
    const [showResults, setShowResults] = useState(false);
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setSearchVal(event.target.value);
        setShowResults(false);
    };

    const handleClick = (event) => {
        setSelectedValue(event.target.value);
        const selectedAddress = addresses.find(
            (address) => address.SEARCHVAL + ' - ' + address.ADDRESS === event.target.value
        );
        const { LATITUDE, LONGITUDE } = selectedAddress;
        props.onCoordinatesChange(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE);
        console.log("Passed in lat and lng" + LATITUDE + LONGITUDE)

    };
    

    const displayResults = () => {
        if (!searchVal) {
            return;
        }
        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('searchVal', searchVal);
        params.append('returnGeom', 'Y');
        params.append('getAddrDetails', 'Y');
        const url =
            'https://developers.onemap.sg/commonapi/search?' + params.toString();
        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setAddresses(data.results);
                setShowResults(true);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error calling API:', error);
            });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="input">Enter Current Location</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    id="input"
                    name="input"
                    value={searchVal}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <button onClick={displayResults}>Search</button>
            </div>
            <br />
            {showResults && (
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="results">Select Current Location:</label>
                    <select id="results" onChange={handleClick} value={selectedValue}>
                        console.log(value)
                        <option disabled defaultValue="" value="">
                            Select Destination
                        </option>
                        {addresses.map((address, index) => (
                            <option
                                key={index}
                                value={address.SEARCHVAL + ' - ' + address.ADDRESS}
                            >
                                {address.SEARCHVAL + ' - ' + address.ADDRESS}
                            </option>
                        ))}
                    </select>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Search;
```

Search component where latitude and longitude are retrieved

I tried to group lat and lng into an array (from mappage) before passing it in into the center property of Simple map. But when i did change my coordinates , it was reflected in console.log(center) but my google map did not recentre based on the received coordinates

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be best for you to provide a codesandbox. Also, have you considered using a more updated react library for google maps? Since the one you're using seems to be old. The same for using class based components.

Comment: Hey. I'm very new to react and not really sure how do I do that. Can you teach me?

Comment: I can't really do much here since you just have to learn and experience more about React. But I would suggest that you read [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) and take some courses like [scrimba](https://scrimba.com/learn/learnreact)

Comment: I'm guessing you just followed along the documentation of the library for `google-map-react` but I don't see you putting a value on your `center` parameter.

Comment: Hey guys, I just found out my the solution to the problem, apparently the object to be passed into center must be in this format {lat: x , lng: y} where x and y are numbers, I was passing in a string value previously for x and y

Comment: Then you can create an answer to your question if you think this would help others also in the future. But please do improve your question like editing it just to show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or a codesandbox that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<SimpleMap center={{ lat: Number(this.state.lat), lng: Number(this.state.lng) }} address={this.state.address}/>
```

Take note that center only accepts an object of {lat: x, lng:y} where x and y are numbers hence the Number() conversion.